# How to copy images in assets to application document directory in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

My flutter app has the following assets.

```
assets:
 - "images/01.png"
 - "images/02.png"
 - "images/03.png"
 ...
```

I'd like to copy these image files to the local path I can get by the following.

```
 Directory docDir = await getApplicattionDocumentsDirectory();
 String localPath = docDir.path;
```

Answer (score 7):

Create a file in your application directory and copy your asset image byte by byte to that file. That's it! You copied your file.

```
final Directory docDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final String localPath = docDir.path;
File file = File('$localPath/${path.split('/').last}');
final imageBytes = await rootBundle.load(path);
final buffer = imageBytes.buffer;
await file.writeAsBytes(
    buffer.asUint8List(imageBytes.offsetInBytes, imageBytes.lengthInBytes));
```

Comment: In your answer, What is path?

Answer (score 0):

getApplicationDocumentsDirectory you need path_provider package.
Suppose you want to copy an m4a file to your application document directory

pubspec.yaml

```
 assets:
    - assets/audio/no_sound_3n.m4a
```

Your code

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

final Directory docDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final String localPath = docDir.path;
File file = File(localPath);
final asset = await rootBundle.load("assets/audio/no_sound_3n.m4a");
final buffer = asset.buffer;
await file.writeAsBytes(
    buffer.asUint8List(asset.offsetInBytes, asset.lengthInBytes));
```

You asset folder

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I too couldn't find a way yet. A way to mitigate this is following the [assets guide](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images), by specifying

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
```

And load arbitrary files via `rootBundle`

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/index.html');
}
```

or in your case using `AssetImage`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // ...
  return DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('graphics/background.png'),
        // ...
      ),
  // ...
    ),
  );
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This thread is pretty old, but in case anyone is still looking for an answer, this is how I did it :)

```
  rootBundle.load('assets/test.jpg').then((content) {
    File newFile = File('${dir.path}/img.jpg');
    newFile.writeAsBytesSync(content.buffer.asUint8List());
    visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(newFile);
    _runAnalysis();
  });
```

Comment: `dir` is not defined